# Laravel query latest record

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

I've this query:

I'm building a forum and I would like to show the latest message that has being posted. I'm doing that like this:

```
return Forum::with(['users' => function($query){
            $query->select('user.id', 'user.name', 'user.last_name')
}]);
```

**forum model:**

```
/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'message');
}
```

How do I only receive the latest user. Right now I receive them all.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Wouldn't `$query->select('user.id', 'user.name', 'user.last_name')->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'message')->orderBy('id', 'desc');
}
```

If you want to limit the number of users returned, append `->take(10);` to take only last 10 users